# Execute php code depending on browser screen size and media-queries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have two php blocks of code (below), which I want to execute depending on the browser screen size, inside a foreach loop, for example, the first code contains a css class desktop-display, the code should execute and output the results when the screen size is equal or greater than 1024px. In the second php code block, the code must execute when the screen size is between 768 and 1023px. I cannot figure how how to do that, hiding and showing php code based on media-queries. When I put these code blocks together, the code simply doesn't execute, if you have solved similar problems before, please share.

```
<style>

.desktop-display {
   display: none;
}
.ipad-portrait {
  display: none;
}

.ipad-landscape {
  display: none;
}

.smartphone-display {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
.desktop-display {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px){
.ipad-landscape {
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>


<?php if ($index == 0 || $index == 2) { ?>
<div style="" class="cne-package the-feed-item desktop-display">
    <div  class="cne-container package package-paired">
        <div class="package__main">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url($video->getProperties(), 'media_video_view'); ?>" style="" class="package__title"><?php echo $video->title; ?></a>
            <div class="package__secondary">
                <div class="package__secondary__inner">
                    <div class="package__secondary__inner__cell">
                        <?php } elseif ($index == 1 || $index == 3) { ?>
                        <div class="package__image--secondary" style="width: 230px; height: 230px; background-image: url(<?php echo $video->getPoster('medium'); ?>);">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->url($video->getProperties(), 'media_video_view'); ?>" style="">
                                <div data-label="<?php echo $video->duration; ?>" class="thumbnail-action-button icon-play the-thumnbail-action-button"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<?php if ($index == 0 || $index == 2) { ?>
<div style="" class="cne-package the-feed-item ipad-landscape">
    <div  class="cne-container package package-paired">
        <div class="package__main">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url($video->getProperties(), 'media_video_view'); ?>" style="" class="package__title"><?php echo $video->title; ?></a>
            <div class="package__secondary">
                <div class="package__secondary__inner">
                    <div class="package__secondary__inner__cell">
                        <?php } elseif ($index == 1 || $index == 3) { ?>
                        <div class="package__image--secondary" style="width: 230px; height: 230px; background-image: url(<?php echo $video->getPoster('medium'); ?>);">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->url($video->getProperties(), 'media_video_view'); ?>" style="">
                                <div data-label="<?php echo $video->duration; ?>" class="thumbnail-action-button icon-play the-thumnbail-action-button"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is run server side, to give it the screen dimensions (which is client side data) you need javascript to send the data to the server.

If Adaptive website is your approach and you wish to do it this way, keep a separate php script for it.

File structure

```
+---> main.php
+---> mobile_view.php
+---> desktop.php
```

and let main.php contain this logic:-

```
var $dimensions = $_GET['dimensions'];
if(dimensions[0] < 1024) {
 // redirect with desktop.php
} else {
 // redirect with mobile.php
}
```